# Increase the file size limitation in crypto-js encryption

Tags: javascript, encryption, client-side, cryptojs

I have come across a tutorial that shows you how to encrypt files in the client-side encryption model using the crypto-js library and the problem is that the tutorial has created a limitation for the file size to be 1MB and I want to increase the limitation of this.

My question is how can I achieve that?

The tutorial: https://tutorialzine.com/2013/11/javascript-file-encrypter

Answer (score 0):

Change the value in the conditional check below (this snippet is from the tutorial link you referenced) to something larger.

1024 bytes is 1KB, multiplied by 1024 is 1 MB.  As an example, if you want the limit to be 5 MB, use `5*1024*1024`.

```
if(file.size > 1024*1024){
  alert('Please choose files smaller than 1mb, otherwise you may crash your browser. \nThis is a known issue. See the tutorial.');
  return;
}
```